# Check if element contains child tag not text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Example HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
<p><img src="..." alt=""/></p>
<p><iframe width="" height="" src="...">....</iframe></p>
<p> Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urn</p>
```

How can I get those p tags efficiently that contain tags instead of text using pure javascript, if possible?

Result should be:

```
<p><img src="..." alt=""/></p>
<p><iframe width="" height="" src="...">....</iframe></p>
```

I have approached it, this way:

```
var ptags = document.querySelectorAll(".container p");
for(var i = 0; i<ptags.length; i++) { 
 if(ptags[i].querySelectorAll("img, iframe").length > 0) { .... }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with actual HTML content, you could use the [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function to grab all of your paragraphs and then use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter out those that did not contain any child elements :

```
// Grab an array of all of your <p> elements
var paragraphs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'), 0);
// Filter out those paragraphs that do not contain any elements
paragraphs = paragraphs.filter(function(p){ return p.childElementCount > 0; });
```

Based on your edit, you could simply check the [`childElementCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/childElementCount) property of each of your elements in your loop :

```
for(var i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) { 
   // Check if this element has children
   if(ptags[i].childElementCount > 0) { 
       // This has children, do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rion, childElementCount property was what I was looking for.